# Small sets in Java: which datastructure?

Tags: java, set

Is there any good reference on, or can someone tell me more about, the performance of various Java set implementations on **small** sets (say 1-100 elements)? The O(1) vs O(log n) story is pretty much irrelevant for these sizes, but since I need to handle millions of these small sets, performance certainly does matter. Most references I find don't mention much about this.

I would need to do the following with these sets (only a few times per set usually):

- initializing a new set and/or hard-copy an old one
- adding/removing elements
- iterating over the set
- computing the `hashCode()` of the entire set

I think these are the viable options to compare (assumed comparing/hashing T is almost free):

- **HashSet<T>**: seems to be bad at iterating (and hence at `hashCode()`)
- **TreeSet<T>**: seems to have ridiculously high overhead
- **LinkedHashSet<T>**: no experience with this at all, does it have high overhead?
- **ArrayList<T>**: fast in itself but not a set, so ugly tricks like `Collections.sort()` needed...

Which of the above is generally preferred? Or should I write my own `SmallSet<T>` class?

Comment: Here's another one if you really only have ten possible elements: `boolean[]`.

Comment: Nono, the sets themselves have small sizes, but their contents can be any object of type T, and there can potentially be tens of thousands different <T> objects. So `boolean[]`, `BitSet` or anything similar, is definitely not an option.

Comment: Unless you're into premature optimization and it really is critical, you should consider JNI for up to [double performance](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php).

Comment: If it has to work with any kind of object I doubt you can do much better than the generic sets offered by the JDK. For optimized performance you probably need to be able to make extra assumptions.

Comment: Comparing/hashing is free (hash is cached and comparing compares the hash), the sets are very small, and I'm only interested in the 4 operations listed there. Those seem like quite specific extra assumptions, or not?

Comment: @user1111929: Comparing does not only compare the hash. Otherwise hash collisions would be a disaster.

Comment: But I know (provably) that for all types <T> I want to use, hash collisions do not exist. :)

Comment: @JonasByström - Your comment makes no sense to me.  1) Premature optimization is about the decision to optimize, not the technique that you use.  2) JNI would be a bad optimization choice for a "set of object" type.  Given the hoops that you have to jump through in JNI when calling methods on Java objects, etcetera, I wouldn't be surprised if a native code implementation was actually slower than a Java one.

Comment: Would it help if you extend AbstractSet (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) and create your own customized set implementation?

Comment: @Stephen C: that is a common standpoint for Java and C# supporters, but the answer is of course that it depends. I don't doubt the hoops are plentiful and dumb, but I still think JNI should be considered as it usually yields [double performance](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php). In practice that is, in theory they're the same...

Comment: @JonasByström - I don't see what that link shows.  It is not meaningful to take large native FORTRAN applications, compare them with large Java applications, and conclude that this has relevance to using JNI to call (probably) small C library methods where the C library method would need to make JNI callbacks each time it touched a Java object.  You are comparing Apples and Pademelons!

Comment: @StephenC: it shows that although many claims that Java is super-fast, it usually is not. The callbacks you presume we need, we don't know for sure, and that's where my recommendation comes in. *Not* considering this option is like *not* comparing Apples and Pademelons, which might be just as bad.

Comment: @JonasByström - It is impossible to implement the `Set` contract without the naive code calling various Java methods on set element objects, and allocating Java objects.  These are JNI calls.  I considered the option, and I dismissed on the basis of what I know a native implementation would need to look like, and what JNI calls the native code would need to make.  And your Strawman argument about people claiming that Java is fast is just plain irrelevant.  This is NOT about Java versus Xyz speed.  This is about using JNI to call Xyz from Java to implement a data structure.

Comment: @StephenC: using Set is another assumption, there is nothing in the question indicating that keeping the data structure  entirely outside Java is not an option (and so it should be considered). It would yield better packing and less cache misses, which is vital when having millions of small structures. No Strawman here, you're obviously biased as you dismiss JNI so easily without further information.

Comment: I'm dismissing JNI based on **lots** of information ... including actually knowing how JNI works, and actually knowing what would be necessary to implement a viable Java set-of-object data structure in native code via JNI.  If you think I'm wrong, prove it.  Implement it, and show that it is faster than an equivalent pure Java implementation of the same API.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really looking for performance, then there's nothing short of testing for yourself that will help you here:

- Are you constantly allocating them new? if so, garbage collection might be more relevant than in other cases
- Are you allocating them once and need quick access? Hashcollisions will have an effect on that
- Are you constantly changing them?

You'll need to setup a testcase that is similar to your actual use - test long enough that GC kicks in and you see the effects there.

And if you detect critical differences between them, rerun the tests after each and every update of the JVM as the implementations might change.

Until you have done such performance tests, I will give my standard advice: Choose the best readable option and only change that when there are obvious gains from using a less readable. The code maintainers (might be a future you) will thank you for that.

Comment: What have you seen from your testing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a small Set implementation as arrays:

It is so easy to adopt to your needs :)

Source:  https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/ultimate-sets-and-maps-for-java-p1/

```
public class ArraySet {
    private int[] array;
    private int size = 0;

    public ArraySet(int capacity) {
        array = new int[capacity];
        Arrays.fill(array, -1);
    }

    public boolean add(int key) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, 0, size, key);
        if (index < 0) {
            int insertIndex = -index-1;

            if(size < array.length - 1) {
                if(insertIndex < size) {
                    System.arraycopy(array, insertIndex, array, insertIndex + 1, size - insertIndex);
                }
                array[insertIndex] = key;
            } else {
                int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, insertIndex);
                System.arraycopy(array, insertIndex, newArray, insertIndex + 1, array.length - insertIndex);
                newArray[insertIndex] = key;
                array = newArray;
            }

            size++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int get(int position) {
        return array[position];
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean contains(int key) {
        return Arrays.binarySearch(array, key) >= 0;
    }
}
```